# Issue with UITableView scroll on iOS where my table header isn't scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's a breakdown of my `UIView`:

- `UIView` at the top. I'm using this as a container view that has other objects in it.
- `UITableView` below the container view.

I want the scrolling to start with the UITableView going over the container view and then scroll through the contents of the table.

I want my table to have a header view that will stick to the top under my `UINavigationController`.

If I do something like `myTableView.tableHeaderView`, it scrolls under the navigation bar.

If I use the table view methods to add a header view, it's frozen in the middle of the screen (where it starts).

Here's my viewDidLayoutSubviews code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.myTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.containerView.bounds.size.height, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f)];
    [self.myTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];

    float headerImageYOffset = 88 + self.containerView.bounds.size.height - self.view.bounds.size.height;
    CGRect headerImageFrame = self.containerView.frame;
    headerImageFrame.origin.y = headerImageYOffset;
}
```

Here's my header code and scroll code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // This is made in Interface Builder
    return self.headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat scrollOffset = -scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat yPos = scrollOffset - _containerView.bounds.size.height;
    _containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPos, _containerView.frame.size.width, _containerView.frame.size.height);   
}
```

What needs to be improved to allow the header to scroll with the table and stay under the navigation bar at the top?

If other code needs to be seen please let me know.

EDIT:

I added more code that goes with what I'm trying to accomplish. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`, just add an auto layout constraint between the parent of the table view and the header:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLayoutConstraint* contraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:self.topLayoutGuide.length];
    [self.view addConstraint:contraint];
}
```

Comment: Removing my scrollViewDidScroll method takes away the effect I'm going for though.